# Show text when loading leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a leaflet map that shows nearby loactions based on geolocation.
But it takes a few seconds before the map is loaded. Is there a way show **Loading...** until the map is loaded?

Comment: Please show us a code example of what you have implemented. Otherwise this question is too broad and would potentially incur opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the question whitout code, but the problem is solved.
Adding this code shows the loading text until the map is loaded!

```
<div id="mapid" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>

<script>
document.getElementById('mapid').innerHTML+= "<center>loading...</center>";
...
</script>
```

Comment: You don't even need JavaScript to do that. Just do this: `<div id="mapid" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;">Loading...</div>`.

Comment: Hi @MosheKatz thaks for this useful tip, that's a lot easier!!!! I try this in the next days :-)